# MessageBox only displaying one character

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

Why does this only print one character for both the title and within the box. How do I make sure it prints it all?

```
import ctypes 
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, "info", "title", 3)
```

only 'i' gets printed and only 't' gets printed for the title, what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you test

```
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "info", "title", 3)
```

there should be "info" and "title". Also if you test

```
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, "info".encode('ascii'), 
                                 "title".encode('ascii'), 3)
```

So it seems to be some sort of text encoding issue. UTF-16-le encoded strings are probably passed by default.

```
>>> 'info'.encode('utf-16-le')
b'i\x00n\x00f\x00o\x00'
>>> 'title'.encode('utf-16-le')
b't\x00i\x00t\x00l\x00e\x00'
```

Since `MessageBoxA` expects `NULL` terminated C strings, only two characters from the beginning, i.e. `'i\0'` and `'t\0'`, were taken into account.

Comment: `ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, b'info', b'title', 3)` is also fine